# Spark on YARN + Secured hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, kerberos, hadoop2, spark-structured-streaming

I am submitting a job to YARN (on spark 2.1.1 + kafka 0.10.2.1) which connects to a secured hbase cluster.  This job, performs just fine when i am running in "local" mode (spark.master=local[*]).

However, as soon as I submit the job with master as YARN (and deploy mode as client), I see the following error message -

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

I am following hortonworks recommendations for providing information to yarn cluster regarding the HBase and keytab etc. Followed this kb article - https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/48988/how-to-run-spark-job-to-interact-with-secured-hbas.html

Any pointers what could be going on ?

the mechanism for logging into HBase:

```
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hbaseConf)
val keyTab = "keytab-location") 
val principal = "kerberos-principal"
val ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principal, keyTab)
UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(ugi)
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction[Void]() {

override def run: Void = {
  hbaseCon = Some(ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConf))
  null
}
})
```

Also, I tried the alternative mechanism for logging in, as:

```scala
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keyTab)
connection=ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConf)
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 14):

You are not alone in the quest for Kerberos auth to HBase from Spark, cf. [SPARK-12279](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12279)

A little-known fact is that Spark now generates **Hadoop "auth tokens"** for Yarn, HDFS, Hive, HBase **on startup**. These tokens are then broadcasted to the executors, so that they don't have to mess again with Kerberos auth, keytabs, etc.

The first problem is that it's not explicitly documented, and in case of failure the errors are hidden by default *(i.e. most people don't connect to HBase with Kerberos, so it's usually pointless to state that the HBase JARs are not in the CLASSPATH and no HBase token was created... usually.)*
To log all details about these tokens, you have to set the log level for `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client` to DEBUG.

The second problem is that beyond the properties, Spark supports many env variables, some documented, some not documented, and some actually deprecated.
For instance, `SPARK_CLASSPATH` is now deprecated, and its content actually injected in Spark properties `spark.driver` / `spark.executor.extraClassPath`.
But `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` is still in use, and in the Cloudera distro for example, it is used to inject the core Hadoop libs & config into the Spark "launcher" so that it can bootstrap a YARN-cluster execution, before the driver is started (i.e. before `spark.driver.extraClassPath` is evaluated).
Other variables of interest are

- `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`
- `SPARK_CONF_DIR`
- `SPARK_EXTRA_LIB_PATH`
- `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS`
- `SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND`

The third problem is that, in some specific cases (e.g. YARN-cluster mode in the Cloudera distro), the Spark property **`spark.yarn.tokens.hbase.enabled`** is set silently to **`false`** -- which makes absolutely no sense, that default is hard-coded to `true` in Spark source code...!
So you are advised to force it explicitly to `true` in your job config.

The fourth problem is that, even if the HBase token has been created at startup, then the executors must explicitly use it to authenticate. Fortunately, Cloudera has contributed a "Spark connector" to HBase, to take care of this kind of nasty stuff automatically. It's now part of the HBase client, by default (cf. `hbase-spark*.jar`).

The fifth problem is that, AFAIK, if you don't have **`metrics-core*.jar`** in the CLASSPATH then the HBase connections will fail with puzzling (and unrelated) ZooKepper errors.

---

¤¤¤¤¤ ***How to make that stuff work, with debug traces***

```
# we assume that spark-env.sh and spark-default.conf are already Hadoop-ready,
# and also *almost* HBase-ready (as in a CDH distro);
# especially HADOOP_CONF_DIR and SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH are expected to be set
# but spark.*.extraClassPath / .extraJavaOptions are expected to be unset

KRB_DEBUG_OPTS="-Dlog4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client=DEBUG -Dlog4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper=DEBUG -Dlog4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation=DEBUG -Dlog4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseContext=DEBUG -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext"
EXTRA_HBASE_CP=/etc/hbase/conf/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-spark.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar

export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS="$KRB_DEBUG_OPTS"
export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true
export SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=True

spark-submit --master yarn-client \
  --files "/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties#yarn-log4j.properties" \
  --principal XX@Z.NET --keytab /a/b/XX.keytab \
  --conf spark.yarn.tokens.hbase.enabled=true \
  --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=$EXTRA_HBASE_CP \
  --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=$EXTRA_HBASE_CP \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=$KRB_DEBUG_OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=yarn-log4j.properties" \
  --conf spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true \
  --class TestSparkHBase  TestSparkHBase.jar

spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --conf spark.yarn.report.interval=4000 \
  --files "/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties#yarn-log4j.properties" \
  --principal XX@Z.NET --keytab /a/b/XX.keytab \
  --conf spark.yarn.tokens.hbase.enabled=true \
  --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=$EXTRA_HBASE_CP \
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=$KRB_DEBUG_OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=yarn-log4j.properties" \
  --conf spark.driverEnv.HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true \
  --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=$EXTRA_HBASE_CP \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=$KRB_DEBUG_OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=yarn-log4j.properties" \
  --conf spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true \
  --class TestSparkHBase  TestSparkHBase.jar
```

PS: when using a `HBaseContext` you don't need `/etc/hbase/conf/` in the executor's CLASSPATH, the conf is propagated automatically.

PPS: I advise you to set `log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper=WARN` in `log4j.properties` because it's verbose, useless, and even confusing (all the interesting stuff is logged at HBase level)

PPS: instead of that verbose `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS` var, you could also list statically the Log4J options in `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/log4j.properties` and the rest in `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/java-opts`; same goes for the Spark properties in `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-defaults.conf` and env variables in `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-env.sh`

---

¤¤¤¤¤ ***About the "Spark connector" to HBase***

Excerpt from the [official HBase documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_basic_spark), chapter 83 *Basic Spark*

> At the root of all Spark and HBase integration is the `HBaseContext`.
>   The `HBaseContext` takes in HBase configurations and pushes them to
>   the Spark executors. This allows us to have an HBase Connection per
>   Spark Executor in a static location.

What is not mentioned in the doc is that the `HBaseContext` uses automatically the HBase "auth token" (when present) to authenticate the executors.

Note also that the doc has an example (in Scala then in Java) of a Spark `foreachPartition` operation on a RDD, using a `BufferedMutator` for async bulk load into HBase.