# kerberos authentication in Kudu for spark2 job

Tags: kerberos, cloudera, apache-kudu, apache-spark-2.2

I am trying to put some data in kudu, but the worker cannot find the kerberos token, so I am not able to put some data into the kudu database.

here you can see my spark2-submit statement

```
spark2-submit --master yarn "spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1" --conf "spark.authenticate=true" --deploy-mode cluster --properties-file ./custom.properties --keytab /home/stream_ingest/stream_ingest.keytab  --principal xxx@xxx --class app.test.Task
```

the exception is the following:

```
18/06/08 08:33:02 INFO client.ConnectToCluster: Unable to connect to master xxx:7051: server requires authentication, but client does not have Kerberos credentials (tgt). Authentication tokens were not used because no token is available
18/06/08 08:33:02 INFO client.ConnectToCluster: Unable to connect to master xxx:7051: server requires authentication, but client does not have Kerberos credentials (tgt). Authentication tokens were not used because no token is available
18/06/08 08:33:02 INFO client.ConnectToCluster: Unable to connect to master xxx:7051: server requires authentication, but client does not have Kerberos credentials (tgt). Authentication tokens were not used because no token is available
ERROR: exception occured during an insert to kudu, sending record ConsumerRecord(topic = custom, partition = 0, offset = 120, CreateTime = 1528444250889, checksum = 3907376269, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 1067790, key = null, value = [B@1623bffa) to error topic custom
org.apache.kudu.client.NonRecoverableException: Couldn't find a valid master in (xxx:7051,xxx:7051,xxx:7051). Exceptions received: [org.apache.kudu.client.NonRecoverableException: server requires authentication, but client does not have Kerberos credentials (tgt). Authentication tokens were not used because no token is available, org.apache.kudu.client.NonRecoverableException: server requires authentication, but client does not have Kerberos credentials (tgt). Authentication tokens were not used because no token is available, org.apache.kudu.client.NonRecoverableException: server requires authentication, but client does not have Kerberos credentials (tgt). Authentication tokens were not used because no token is available]
    at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduException.transformException(KuduException.java:110)
    at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduClient.joinAndHandleException(KuduClient.java:352)
    at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduClient.openTable(KuduClient.java:222)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2064)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2064)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: org.apache.kudu.client.KuduException$OriginalException: Original asynchronous stack trace
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster.incrementCountAndCheckExhausted(ConnectToCluster.java:246)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster.access$100(ConnectToCluster.java:49)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster$ConnectToMasterErrCB.call(ConnectToCluster.java:365)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.ConnectToCluster$ConnectToMasterErrCB.call(ConnectToCluster.java:354)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1280)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1259)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.handleContinuation(Deferred.java:1315)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1286)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1259)
        at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.callback(Deferred.java:1002)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduRpc.handleCallback(KuduRpc.java:246)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.KuduRpc.errback(KuduRpc.java:300)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy.responseReceived(RpcProxy.java:221)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy.access$000(RpcProxy.java:60)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy$1.call(RpcProxy.java:132)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.RpcProxy$1.call(RpcProxy.java:128)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.cleanup(Connection.java:715)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:460)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.apache.kudu.client.Connection.handleUpstream(Connection.java:244)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:60)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.messageReceived(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:184)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.apache.kudu.shaded.org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        ... 3 more
```

It looks like that the kudu client does not find the keytab file. In the kudu documentation they mentioned, that you only have to specify the **keytab** and **principal** parameter.

If you execute a openTable on the KuduClient in the driver, everything works fine.

Comment: The executors have no access to the keytab. It's the driver that manages the Kerberos tickets and obatains Hadoop "auth tokens" -- for HDFS and YARN, for Hive Metastore, for HBase... and probably Cloudera also developed an extra "token" for Kudu. Alas, whenever Spark fails to create a token (or it is disabled by configuration) it fails silently.

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265562/spark-on-yarn-secured-hbase for details - and debugging hints.

Comment: review user and password or recreate your keytab because adding  --keytab /../my.keytab  AND  --principal myUSER@MYREALM is enought

Answer (score 0):

While integrating **kudu with Spark**, to **run** the **spark application** in **client** mode you need to do authentication using **kinit** only. If you **run** the **spark application** in **cluster** mode you must need to specify the **keytab** and **principal** to the **spark-submit** to authenticate.

In your case, please check the **principal and keytab** is **correct** by running the sample **SparkPi** example.

For more steps you can go through the following article:

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/tkb/workflowpage/tkb-id/CommunityArticles/article-id/6689

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it might be due to this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KUDU-2679