# How to connect to HBase from spark using Kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

Can anyone please tell me how to connect to HBase from spark using kerberos. Am using the below code to create connection to HBase but its still having issues.

```
 val genericMessage = messages.mapPartitions(iter => {
      val context = TaskContext.get
      logger.info((s"log - Process for partition: ${context.partitionId} "))
      val partitionId: Int = context.partitionId

      val conf: Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
      conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", ZOOKEEPER_QOURUM)
      conf.set("hbase.rpc.timeout", "1800000")
      conf.set("hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period", "1800000")
      conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
      import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation
      UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("customer@mail.com", keyTab)
      val connection: Connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
      val custTable Table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("prod:cusotmer"))

      val avroMessages = iter.map(msg => (msg._1, enrichment(rec._1, decodeBinaryToAvro(rec._2)))
      connection.close()
      custTable.close()
      avroMessages
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: Spark executors have to connect individually to HBase, but they don't have a Kerberos ticket _(except in `local` mode)_. Is that the kind of "issue" you are talking about??

Comment: Also, RTFM > https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#spark > that HBase module (contributed by Cloudera) handles Kerberos out of the box.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, thanks for the reply. I tried to use --principal and --keytab options but still it didnt work. Its throwing NullPointer Exception when I use these options. And if I use the below in code then its throwing Unable to obtain password from user. System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf") UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("customer@CREALM.NET", keyTab)

Comment: Don't try to manage Kerberos authentication inside _executor_ code. The proper way is to let the Spark init obtain "tokens" for HDFS, Hive, HBase etc then broadcast the "tokens" to each executor; the trick is token-based authentication in HBase is not documented... so use the Spark-HBase connector instead, with `HBaseContext`, unless you are ready to read the Spark and HBase code on GitHub and also have several years of experience with Kerberos and the scars to prove it.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265562/spark-on-yarn-secured-hbase

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter for the reply. Appreciate for your time. I have already tried rdd. But am getting the below issue.         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:935)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:901)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: hconnection-0x614c1a0d closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveZooKeeperWatcher(ConnectionManager.java:1806)

Comment: Below is the logic am using     genericMessage.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val getRDD = rdd.hbaseMapPartitions[(String, GenericRecord)](hBaseContext, (it, connection) => {
        val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("test:custTable"))
        it.map{ row =>
          val key = row._1
          val genericRecord = row._2
            val result = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes(imsi)))
            .....
          }
          (key, genericRecord)
        }
      })
    })

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter, can you please help me on this. Its of very high priority for me. I'm using HBaseContext. It works fine when I use BulkGet. But its giving me the above issue when I use hbaseMapPartitions. I think there is some issue when it tries to establish a connection in each mapPartition. I cannot use BulkGet for my requirement as the output of BulkGet is an RDD. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Did not touch to HBase in the last two years...