# Kerberos Authentication in Python/Pyspark using keytab

Tags: python, kerberos

I'm trying to connect to Hadoop/Hive from Intelliji using keytab based authentication in python/pyspark. I use statement in scala to get kerberos ticket but is there any similar way in Python as well to do kerberos authentication.

UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keytabPath)

Comment: From PySpark, you can use the Py4J gateway to invoke any Java method - the syntax is kind of hacky but it works. Google about that.

Comment: hmm I was able to call scala method from python to renew kerberos ticket but it seems pyspark is not recognizing this token. i.e I'm running into below error 

python/src/main/python/com/chase/py4j_test.py
2019-06-29 03:05:47 ERROR TSaslTransport:315 - SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]

Any thought on this?

Comment: Actually the right question to ask was _"how does Spark manage Kerberos auth from its own distributed computing engine to Hadoop distributed computing platform, although Kerberos is for point-to-point auth and **not** for this kind of mess?"_

Comment: And the answer is: **before starting the Driver**, the Spark "client" connects to the cluster and retrieves auth **tokens** to HDFS/Yarn, optionally to HiveMetastore, optionally to HBase. The tokens are broadcast to Driver and Executors, and valid against any Hadoop node for typically 24h.

Comment: So it's too late (and not enough) for you to set up the Hadoop UGI in the driver. Either you create a Kerberos ticket before starting the Spark job, or you pass `principal` and `keytab` as Spark properties, consumed by the "client"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44265562/5162372

Comment: I'm passing the principle and keyab in scala code then below is a python code I'm verifying to make sure the keytab is still valid,

    gateway =     gateway = JavaGateway(gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=25335))
    stack = gateway.entry_point.getStack()
    print("isFromKeytab =" , stack.isFromKeytab() ,"CurrentUser=",stack.getCurrentUser() ,",isLoginKeytabBased = ",stack.isLoginKeytabBased())

the output of above lines is below,

isFromKeytab = True CurrentUser= a_myfid@NAEAST.AD.JPMORGANCHASE.COM (auth:KERBEROS) ,isLoginKeytabBased =  True

then connecting to hdfs/hive

Comment: Read again my comments above. **Spark uses Kerberos at startup only** and does not give a shot at your custom ticket.

Comment: The only thing that would use your custom Kerberos ticket is a JDBC connection (say, to MS SQL Server) with Kerberos auth, because the JDBC driver would manage its own auth with core JAAS libraries.